VS-code remote connection:Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'after')
I installed the latest version of the Remote-SSH extension. When trying to connect or even change the settings of the extension in vs code or even uninstall it I got the error below:
 Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'after')
I saw some solutions to change the pre-release versions or setting "Listen on socket" in settings but in my case, I face the error even when I want to uninstall or change the settings.



Disable ssh remote extension
Close VS Code completely and go to the VS Code extension folder
Make a copy of the extension to another place as backup
Delete it


This helped me to uninstall Remote-SSH but the problem still exists and the error is still the same after the new installation of the extension.

Clear your cache, type Windows + r, write "%tmp%, clear everything and try again.
